# How to ask turtles to stop if other turtles go over a certain patch-colour?

Tags: netlogo

How can I tell a turtle to stop moving if there are other turtles going over a certain patch-color?

For example, I told 4 random patches to turn blue. I want a turtle only to be able to go over these blue patches if no other turtles are going over/are at these blue patches.

I already have this, but it does not seem to work:

```
if any? other turtles-on patches with [pcolor = blue]
[
set speed 0
]
```

Comment: The code you have supplied seems plausible. I suspect the problem is somewhere else in your code.